# Trouble using Manipulate and NDsolve for coupled ODE's

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

I'm aware that there are a few threads on the topic of solving coupled ODEs using `NDSolve` and `Manipulate`. Based on those, I wrote the following code, solving my system of equations:

```
  Manipulate[{Solns = 
   NDSolve[{ee'[t] == -I*c1/2*(ge[t] - eg[t]) - c2*ee[t], 
     gg'[t] == I*c1/2*(ge[t] - eg[t]) + c2*ee[t], 
     ge'[t] == -c2/2*ge[t] + I*c1/2*(gg[t] - ee[t]) - c3/2*ge[t], 
     eg'[t] == -c2/2*eg[t] - I*c1/2*(gg[t] - ee[t]) - c3/2*eg[t], 
     ee[0] == 1, gg[0] == 0, ge[0] == 0, eg[0] == 0}, {ee, gg, ge, 
     eg}, {t, 0, 5}], 
  Plot[{ee[t] /. Solns, gg[t] /. Solns}, {t, 0, 5}]}, {{c1, 0, 
   "Rabi Frequency"}, 0, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c2, 0, "Dephasing"}, 0, 3, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c3, 0, "Spont. Emission"}, 0, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

However, while the code does run (and gives the correct solution), I get this strange screen where I have a bunch of other stuff in the plot box:
[image]

I'm not sure why this is happening, so my question is basically what is causing this unwanted stuff to be plotted. I tried looking for things like InterpolatingFunction inside figure, but no results popped up on that.

Oh, as a side note, these equations can also be solved with `DSolve`, but I want to make some adjustments that no longer allow that type of solution. I just used this because it is close to what I want, and I know what it looks like. Moreover, if there would be a way to make the plotting go faster, I'd also be interested in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is `Manipulate[ expression1; expression2;....; expression10, controls]`  you had a `Manipulate[ expression1, expression2, ..., expression10, controls], ie. used`,` in middle of expression. Corrected.

```
Manipulate[
 solns = NDSolve[{
    ee'[t] == -I*c1/2*(ge[t] - eg[t]) - c2*ee[t],
    gg'[t] == I*c1/2*(ge[t] - eg[t]) + c2*ee[t],
    ge'[t] == -c2/2*ge[t] + I*c1/2*(gg[t] - ee[t]) - c3/2*ge[t],
    eg'[t] == -c2/2*eg[t] - I*c1/2*(gg[t] - ee[t]) - c3/2*eg[t],
    ee[0] == 1, gg[0] == 0, ge[0] == 0, eg[0] == 0}, {ee, gg, ge, eg}, {t, 0, 5}];
 Plot[{ee[t] /. solns, gg[t] /. solns}, {t, 0, 5}],
 {{c1, 0, "Rabi Frequency"}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c2, 0, "Dephasing"}, 0, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c3, 0, "Spont. Emission"}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Well, that's embarassing. It's my first time working with Mathematica, so I apologize for the beginners mistake. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I should note (for clarity) that the proper syntax for Manipulate is: `Manipulate[expr, 'controls']`, where 'controls' can take various forms (like lists, `Control[XXX]`, etc...).  Arguments in WL are separated by commas, and the first argument to `Manipulate` is the expression to be manipulated.

The problem in the OP was that the first argument was actually `NDSolve[XXX]` and not the `CompoundExpression` they actually wanted.

Comment: @chuy Yes, of course, I meant to write `Manipulate[expr1;expr2, controls]` the OP had `Manipulate[expr1,expr2, controls]` will correct. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try something like the following where I use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html) (what a mouthful!):

```
solns = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ee'[t] == -I*c1/2*(ge[t] - eg[t]) - 
     c2*ee[t], gg'[t] == I*c1/2*(ge[t] - eg[t]) + c2*ee[t], 
   ge'[t] == -c2/2*ge[t] + I*c1/2*(gg[t] - ee[t]) - c3/2*ge[t], 
   eg'[t] == -c2/2*eg[t] - I*c1/2*(gg[t] - ee[t]) - c3/2*eg[t], 
   ee[0] == 1, gg[0] == 0, ge[0] == 0, eg[0] == 0}, {ee, gg}, {t, 0, 
   5}, {c1, c2, c3}]
```

I see you only wanted `ee` and `gg` to plot so I used those. The result is a [`ParametricFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricFunction.html), which can be rather nicely used in a `Manipulate`.  I think it is also worthwhile to take a quick glance at what `solns` is by feeding it some parameters (here `c1=1`, `c2=2`, and `c3=3`):

```
solns[1, 2, 3]
(* {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 5.}}, <>], 
 InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 5.}}, <>]} *)
```

So it's a `List` of `InterpolatingFunctions`. Moving on to the `Manipulate`

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate@Through[solns[c1, c2, c3][t]], {t, 0, 5}], {{c1, 0, 
   "Rabi Frequency"}, 0, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c2, 0, "Dephasing"}, 0, 3, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c3, 0, "Spont. Emission"}, 0, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

I used [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html) and [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) to 1) apply the list of interpolation functions to the same argument, `t`, and 2) to allow Plot to "see" that the first argument I am giving it is actually a List and not a mulivalued function (this makes the lines different colors).

I also like this because it makes it clearer as to what expression is being manipulated.  In this case it is `Plot[Evaluate@Through[solns[c1, c2, c3][t]], {t, 0, 5}]`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put a semicolon immediately before `Plot`, instead of a comma.